# How to detect if bitmap is too large for texture

Tags: android, opengl-es

So I have done a lot of looking around and the answer to this seems to be to use:

```
 int[] maxSize = new int[1];
 gl.glGetIntegerv(GL10.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, maxSize, 0);
```

to detect the size of the texture, now my issue is how do I create or get access to the `gl` var that holds the function I need? Is it already there somewhere? I would like to support android 2.2 and above, so the 4.0+ new trick wont work. If this is a repeat question just point me in the right direction in the comments and I will take t down. Couldn't seem to find a good explanation of how to set this up properly anywhere, just those two lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look on how OpenGL Apps are made you will notice there are the main app thread (main activity) and a renderer class(http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html). The heart of the renderer class if the method `public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)` , this is called by the android infrastructure when the frame needs to be redraw.

So basically, a context object (`GL10 gl` var) is passed to the renderer (yours) when required and there you can check your max texture size.

Comment: How do I gain access to this thread or that method to run those lines of code?

Comment: Google it, for example: http://blog.uncle.se/2012/02/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-part-i-setting-up-the-view/ explains how to setup a basic renderer.

Comment: thanks, I have spent the past day on google, just was not sure what to google.